# When output to the console, a "%" symbol is added in linux. C++

Tags: c++, linux, shell, zsh, manjaro

I use Manjaro Linux, DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.0.0, GNOME 43.1, Kernel 5.19.17-2, and I used zsh.

I decided to learn C++, but I ran into a problem. If I didn't add `std::endl` when outputting to the console, the symbol "%" is added.

See the screenshots attached.

Code1:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int age;
    age = 28;
    std::cout << "Age = " << age;
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Result1]

Code2:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int age;
    age = 28;
    std::cout << "Age = " << age << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Result2]

Why is this happening? All I tried was just adding `std::endl`. I want to know why the "%" symbol is being added.

Comment: please don't post images of source code. Instead, please just copy the source code here and use the "code formatting" button.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Ok, sorry! One minute

Comment: It's your shell prompt.

Comment: It's not `std::endl` that fixes the problem, but the newline that is part of what `std::endl` does. To write a newline, just use `<< '\n'`. This program, like most, doesn't need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does.

Comment: If you try running `./test ; sleep 5` it will be more obvious what's going on. Or `./test ; echo PROGRAM DONE`. Note that you'll still get the `%` character if your program prints a newline before exiting; it just won't be on the same line as your program's output.

Comment: This is the default value for `PROMPT_EOL_MARK`. See _man zshoptions_, section _Prompting_. The variable is explained in the explanation of the variable `PROMPT_SP`. BTW, I set it in my .zshrc to `PROMPT_EOL_MARK=⁇` (Unicode 2047), because this is IMO more intuitive than a percent sign.

Answer (score 3):

Ah, you're omitting the final line break.

Your shell hence *should* (would it be very true to what your program actually produced in output) display the prompt on the same line as your output.

Now, that would look terrible and be confusing. So, instead your shell inserts a special character with a special background color to mark "hey, this isn't the program's output, but I'm still inserting a line break here, because I don't hate you, dear user".

That percentage symbol is not from your program. It's your shell trying to be sensible.

Comment: And how to fix it, are there any options?
I just look at the course and it says the same thing and the conclusion is correct. If it's not difficult for you, could you suggest

Comment: There's nothing to fix other than actually printing a newline. What's broken?

Answer (score 1):

From the man page for zsh:

> When a partial line is preserved, by default you will see an inverse+bold  character at the end of the partial line:  a `%` for a normal user or a `#` for root.  If set, the shell parameter PROMPT_EOL_MARK can be used to customize how the end of  partial lines are shown.